# Avoid any as return type in subclasses

Tags: typescript

I have this class

```ts
class Foo {
  async init() {}
}
```

And this subclass

```ts
class Bar extends Foo {
  async init(): Promise<number> {
    return 3;
  }
  
}
```

I need to prevent that all the subclasses of Foo that overload the method init, can type Promise<any> as the return type, can be anything else unless Promise<any>.

The init method is always asynchronous.

**Update:**

The Foo class in the real code is a class that contains another logics and have another responsibilities, so can't be an abstract class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your class generic, and then subclasses can provide that generic type to declare how they want their `init` to be typed.

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
  abstract init(): Promise<T>
}
```

Here the `Foo` class in generic over type `T`. And the `init` method is typed to return a `Promise` that resolved to whatever `T` is.

I've also made this class abstract since it's incomplete. Without a function that can return `Promise<T>` the class can't be fully valid.

Now you can subclass this like so:

```
class Bar extends Foo<number> {
  async init() {
    return 3;
  }

  async method() {
    const num: number = await this.init() // works
  }
}
```

Here `Bar` extends `Foo<number>`, which means that `init()` must return `Promise<number>`.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wHgBUA+BAbwCgEFRIZ4EBLAOwYgAoBKALgQAUpsAWwZgApoSLkAvuXIo0GAELAoCUQA8IopgBMMOfEwCugkKKgkKVNAE8msRi3YcylKgiiiIRqEwQBmAG43GTdbewRBLwALbB1OV3ckbCZIBGNBHgyzVQBeagB3YFYECGiRADpmVgSAelqEAuwoAGswEOkgA)

---

And if you really wanted to have a concrete class that does not do any `init` then you can just pass the `void` type.

```
class FooNoInit extends Foo<void> {
  async init() {}
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wHgBUA+BAbwCgEFRIZ4EBLAOwYgAoBKALgQAUpsAWwZgApoSLkAvuXIo0GHNgBy2AJItEogB4RRTACaLceAG7YGBkhSpoAnk1iNNnMjKlA)